# WITH (NOLOCK) Giving varying results

Tags: sql-server

At first I thought I should go see my Dr. and have an MRI of my brain.  But, the results I am seeing were confirmed by a second programmer.  Running the same exact SQL is giving me different results at different times!  It makes no sense.  Here is what I am running (table names changed to protect the innocent)...

```sql
declare @customerid int;
declare @locationid int;
declare @reportdate datetime;
set @customerid=2063;
set @locationid=101;
set @reportdate=getdate();

select i.InvoiceDate as [Date], ... from Invoice i (nolock) ...
UNION ALL select ... from Remit e (nolock) ...
UNION ALL select ... from [Rec] r (nolock) join TrTypes t (nolock) on ...
```

The two select/union all's are identical but sometimes the second does not return records from the `Remit` table when the first shows them.  And...  Sometimes the first doesn't pull them either.  I put these queries in `SQL Server Management Studio` and keep hitting `F5`...  Sometime I get proper results, sometimes I don't.

Further, when I remove the `UNION ALL`s and just run the queries, **nothing** is returned from `Remit`.

Could this be a locking issue?

This query is from a `C#` program that produces a detail report and it **never** returns the Remit records.  There is another program that creates summary records from the `Remit` table and it **always** returns the records from a similar query...  That is why I had to look at the detail program/report.

Thoughts?

Comment: You're using `NOLOCK` and then wondering why you get different results at different times?

Comment: [Article no 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx), [article no 2](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/beware-nolock-hint), [article no 3](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/06/the-side-effect-of-nolock/), [article no 4](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/11/10/1280.aspx).. etc.

Comment: I understand why you might believe NOLOCK would cause this issue, but it was not the case here.  The problem was getdate() in the where clause of the Remit table.

Comment: OMG, you were using the mother of all nondeterministic functions in SQL Server and were wondering why you'd get different results? :)

Comment: @kc7rad If the `GETDATE()` was the culprit in the `WHERE` clause then the inconsistency would still be due to the use of `NOLOCK`s on your tables for which you are evaluating the GETDATE() value against. The only time `GETDATE()` is usually an issue is when you use the function multiple times in different places getting different values, but you actually did the proper thing and populated a variable to get a static value. The issue is that you have no way of knowing what is truly in all your tables when you use NOLOCK against them.

Answer (score 8):

`NOLOCK` means you don't care about consistency, concurrency and locking/blocking. It allows you to read the same row 0 times, 1 time, or 2 times. It is not a magic "go faster" button for queries: you should only use it if you fully understand the potential consequences on a busy system (such as getting different results at different times!).

The solution is to either:

1. stop blindly throwing `NOLOCK` everywhere (accept your blocking to get accurate and consistent data, or use read committed snapshot isolation).
2. accept that `NOLOCK` sacrifices accuracy for less blocking, and sometimes it just won't give the right results. If you ask for this, you don't get to complain about it.

Comment: I just removed all NOLOCK s from the query and results are the same.  Our use of NOLOCK is a defacto standard at our shop.  Never seen this before.

Comment: @kc7rad so you're saying you removed all of the NOLOCK hints, and when you run the query twice a few seconds apart, you are getting different results? Not to say I don't believe you, but I don't believe you. The only way a READ COMMITTED query (the default) will return different results between executions is if the underlying data *has actually changed*.

Comment: You might have never *seen* it before but that's all the worse. How many times have you given your users inconsistent results without their knowledge?

Comment: NOLOCK is not the issue at all.  It is with the (isnull(e.Post_Date,getdate()) <= @ReportDate) .  That was returning varying results.  I changed it to this and I am now getting consistent results.  (isnull(e.Post_Date,@ReportDate) <= @ReportDate)  Was getdate() returning inconsistent results?  The underlying data is not changing...  It is in a static environment.  Aaron, I don't blame you for not believing me, I wouldn't believe it if I hadn't seen it myself.

Comment: *Was getdate() returning inconsistent results?* No, it is returning consistent but different results. Time changes ...

Comment: If you're in a static environment where data never changes then why are you using `NOLOCK`?